# How can I use a single quote to split one column into two within a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column (`samplename_date`) of a dataframe that looks as follows:

> '008Q06-03 RGD17-48 3.8W Wm 1xtl'   03 July

I'm trying to split this into two columns, after the second single quote.  I've been trying:

`temp[['samplename','date']] = df['samplename_date'].str.split(''\s', expand = True)`

and variations thereof, but I can't seem to figure out how to handle the single quote in the regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape single quote as well

```
temp[['samplename','date']] = df['samplename_date'].str.split('\'\s', expand = True)
```

You get

```
    samplename                          date
0   '008Q06-03 RGD17-48 3.8W Wm 1xtl    03 July
```

I would personally use str.extract

```
temp[['samplename','date']] = df['samplename_date'].str.extract('\'(.*)\'\s(.*)', expand = True)


    samplename                      date
0   008Q06-03 RGD17-48 3.8W Wm 1xtl 03 July
```

Comment: It will leave the starting quote `'` which might not be required

Comment: Oh, haha thank you!  That was actually a variation I had tried, I was under the impression it wasn't working...because I hadn't scrolled down in my Jupyter window to find the new columns.  Well, that was a horrible waste of several hours.  Thanks though!

Comment: @Dan, no problems :)